# JS framework for dynamic website

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I need framework with following features:
    - Simple templating
    - ajax loading of webpages
    - dynamic models (so when I update model, page is changed)
    - In-browser validation of data in forms (this can be done using some another library)

I want to write website, where user can visit all pages without reloading (only one GET request for first page load and then all pages are received via ajax)

I know about React.js, but I think it is a bit complicated.
Backend of website is Laravel.

The best will be a simple tutorial for creating website using this framework so I can understand if it suits my needs.

I want to write some kind of reusable html so that I can specify for all tags, forms, inputs required parameters and it is automatically loaded, validated and so on.

Like this (required attribute guarantes that client sees validation error before submit, data-integer attribute guarantees that user can not input somethinh other than integer and so on). Of course it is pure client side validation, server must validate it too.

```
<form data-api='/api/v1/post-form-1' data-result-selector='#id-of-tag-where-result-will-be-written-in-html-on-form-submit'>
    <input type='text' required>
</form>

<form data-api='/api/v1/post-form-2' data-result-selector='#id-of-tag-where-result-will-be-written-in-html-on-form-submit-2'>
            <input type='text' data-integer=true>
</form>
```

Comment: You can have a look into Vue.js it's lightweight and easy to adopt. There is a video tutorial series about Vue.js at Laracasts. https://laracasts.com/series/learning-vue-step-by-step/

Comment: Do I correctly understand that I need to write some code to deal with models? Get data in json via ajax and assign data.

Comment: Vue has a library called vue-resource to deal with AJAX https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is a generic question , and from your viewpoint on react , think you should have a look on [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) which will work great with laravel backend .

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this page:
http://todomvc.com/

Cheers